# C#: How to add anonymous type to HttpResponseMessage object that already exists?

Tags: asp.net

My Web API project currently uses this method to return content to the server to deliver to the client:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,someAnonymouslyTypedVariableHere);
```

ASP.NET will automatically select the correct serializer based on the `Accept` header.

However, I want to be able to create my response object earlier in code and then populate it as necessary. Like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage m = Request.CreateResponse();
// a bunch of stuff happens here
var someAnonymouslyTypedVariableHere = new { ... }
m.Status = HttpStatusCode.OK;
m.Content = ???
// potentially other code here
return m;
```

I found that I cannot create an object of type `ObjectContent` without providing a serializer. This means that I would lose the automatic serializer detection based on the Accept header.

Is there any way to assign the ObjectContent to the existing HttpResponseMessage while still allowing ASP.NET to select the right serializer?

The reason I would want to do this at all is more for code readability and optimization. There are times where I may have data ready for the HttpResponseMessage but am not ready to return it. So rather than doing `return Request.CreateResponse...` at every single point where I might return, I'd rather generate the `HttpResponseMessage` object up front, populate it as the code runs, and finally return it.

Sure I could store this data in variables and then return it at the end. But suppose for example, in one code flow I need a `StringContent` content rather than `ObjectContent`. Thus my need to be able to dynamically set content on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code snippet on the Web that appears to do what I'm looking for.

```
    IContentNegotiator negotiator = this.Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();

    ContentNegotiationResult result = negotiator.Negotiate(
        typeof(myVar), this.Request, this.Configuration.Formatters);
    if (result == null)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
        throw new HttpResponseException(response));
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent(
            myVar,              // What we are serializing 
            result.Formatter,           // The media formatter
            result.MediaType.MediaType  // The MIME type
        )
    };
}
```

The key here is the ContentNegotiator which should be able to do what I need.